# How to achieve a specialized redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have an odd use for htaccess redirect.  I have an affiliate system that uses compiled code to produce it's output.  (I hate compiled php by the way as you can't fix the developers goofs).

In some cases the prefix to the theme directory is like this:

html/themes/xblue/....

which works, but in some cases it's like this:

`html/themes//....`

Leaving out the word "xblue", but otherwise correct.

I need to be able to redirect html/themes// to html/themes/xblue/

I've tried the following redirect statements:

```
# Redirect 301 /affiliates/includes/html/themes//   /affiliates/includes/html/themes/xblue/
# Redirect 301 // /xblue/
```

Neither one works, but gives an infinite number of redirects and breaks the page.

Do you know how I can redirect `"themes//"` to `"themes/xblue/"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with negative lookahead as your very first rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*/themes)/(?!xblue/)(.*)$ /$1/xblue/$2
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.